# Run C function in background in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, multithreading

I want to call a C function in a Objective-C app. The function contains an endless loop. So I need to run this C function in **background**.

Here's my C function:

```
int go(){
    for(;;){
        //...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the call:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:go() withObject:nil];
```

The function `go()` is called but it's not running in background (and the app stop working...).

Comment: Whatever it is you're doing, the odds are very good that there's a much better way to do it.  Can you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you have a lot of array processing in `go()`?

Comment: No, `go()` starts a websocket server

Comment: Use Objective-C "glue" code to invoke your C method.

Comment: @HotLicks Can you cite a reference to this "glue"? Would like to read up on that.

Comment: @fa7d0 If that socket server is coming from some cross platform library, then -- maybe -- it is OK.  In general, though, you're program will be more efficient (and use less power) if it embraces the system APIs.   That isn't always viable, certainly.

Comment: "Glue" is what's referred to below as a "wrapper method" -- a trivial method written in one language that invokes a method of another language.

Comment: @bbum I agree. I have "reinvented the wheel" only for a personal goal. For a more "serious" project I would have done it with system APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in the background you probably should run something in an endless loop. However it is possible.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:<selector> withObject:<Object>];
```

That is a nice convenience method to just throw a method to the background thread. But you also have access to Grand Central Dispatch that would let you put blocks of code into a background thread as well. You could even give it a private queue so it wouldn't block your background queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // Your code
    go();
});
```

Comment: A simple ObjC method wrapper would also work like nhgrif suggested but as I mentioned you may want to give it a private background thread rather than blocking your background thread indefinitely.

Comment: Glad I could help. I encourage you to listen to some of the comments and dig a bit deeper. Web Sockets are a much explored subject so its very possible something like Rocket or AFNetworking can provide support above and beyond what Apple has already provided. Don't reinvent the wheel when you don't have to past academic exercise. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, there may be an easier way, but...

```
- (int)doGo {
    return go();
}
```

Then...

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doGo) withObject:nil];
```

---

So, this answer really just highlights what I believe is the most fundamental problem with your provided code, but you should certainly see Ryan's answer and use GCD.  `performSelectorInBackground:` really isn't all that great.